# Use a foreign key with DbContext and Lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I should know how to retrieve data using a foreign key and `DbSet`, example:

```
_context.Orders.Include("Operator");
```

but I don't understand how to do this if the main model is a `List`:

```
public class LiveData
{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
{

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int OperatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}
```

Operator is defined as follow:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public IConnectionManager ConnectionManager { get; set; }
    public MyContext() : base("MyContext") { }

    public DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
}

public class Operator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

now in my Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyContext _context { get; set; }
    public LiveData _liveData { get; set; }

    public MyController(MyContext context, LiveData liveData)
    {
        _context = context;
        _liveData = liveData;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_liveData.Orders.ToList());
    }
}
```

but the `Operator` field is not retrieved (is null). As far as I know it's due to lazy loading, and for this reason I should use `.Include("Operator")`. Unfortunately the `Include` method is not available for `List`.

A workaround could be manually query the related table for each `Order` record, but I guess there is a better way.

### UPDATE

LiveData, like the name suggest, is a RAM variable (non-persistent) that is created and populated at run-time:

```
public class AutofacContainer
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }
    public AutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<LiveData>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<Erp>().PropertiesAutowired();

        Container = builder.Build();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(Container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));
    }
}
```

and in an initialization class:

```
public class Erp 
{
    public MyContext _context { get; set; }
    public LiveData _liveData { get; set; }

    public Erp(MyContext context, LiveData liveData)
    {
        _context = context;
        _liveData = liveData;

        // do some I/O operation to retrieve current orders from field (serial communication) and store it in a var Lines

        foreach (var line in Lines)
        { 
            Order order = new Order();
            // process line and fill fields

            _liveData.Orders.Add(order);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the parameter `liveData` come from? Anyway, how to use `Include` on collections is a trivial question.

Comment: I inject it using Autofac. I apologize for the trivial question, I'm new to C# and perhaps I searched with wrong words because something like "how to use Include in List" doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you injected it. What I meant to ask is: how is `liveData` generated? By which code? Why does it even have `Orders`?

Comment: You can't perform Include for a list. "List" is already retrieved from database.  So, "_context.Orders.Include("Operator");" do you use to fill liveData ?

Comment: @Rainman you're right, the "ToList()" is redundant here. I kept it when creating the Controller from another that used the DbContext directly. I update the question with details about LiveData

Comment: I see that you are not using context to fill LiveData ? Am I right ? Also, where are you registering Erp, I couldn't understand too.

Comment: Still not clear. Wherever *lines* comes from -- there must always be some `DbSet` in a context involved to call `Include`. Where you create the `new Order()` you also have to populate the `Operator`.

Comment: Yes, correct. LiveData is **not** filled by context, but by "live" data that coming for the external world. I'm sorry, I forgot to copy&paste the Erp line. Is there now (in Autofac builder).

Comment: @GertArnold as said *lines* come from an I/O operation (a serial communication with an external device). I fill the OperatorId (foreign key) with 0.